# ELI5 — phone v. phoneme v. allophone

Tags: terminology

Please ELI5? I read the websites beneath but I still feel befuddled. Are there simple real-life analogies?

### [Can someone explain to me the difference between a phone, phoneme, and allophone? (reposted from r/linguistics : asklinguistics](https://old.reddit.com/r/asklinguistics/comments/4mfsu9/can_someone_explain_to_me_the_difference_between/)

> a *phone* is a single sound that comes out of your mouth. The glottal stop is a phone.
>
> a *phoneme* is the group of sounds that distinguish meanings within a language. The glottal stop is not a phoneme in standard dialects of English because they don't use it to distinguish between words.
>
> an *allophone* is a collection of phones that shows up as the form of a phoneme either some of the time or under certain circumstances. In some dialects of English, the glottal stop is an allophone of the phoneme /t/ when it occurs between vowels or before liquids.

### [Phoneme – sound – allophone – phone | BLOG|ON|LINGUISTICS](https://blogonlinguistics.wordpress.com/2013/10/12/phoneme-sound-allophone-phone/)

> **Phoneme** (Gr. *phone* “sound, voice”) is the smallest contrastive unit of language that may change the meaning of a morpheme and, as a pursuant, a word.
>
> **Sound** (=**phone**) is a vibration or wave caused by an object.
>
> **Allophone** (Gr. *allos* “other” and *phone* “sound, voice”) is a variant of a phoneme.

### [What is the difference between phoneme, phone and allophone? - Bayt.com Specialties](https://specialties.bayt.com/en/specialties/q/23493/what-is-the-difference-between-phoneme-phone-and-allophone/)

> - A phoneme is the smallest contrastive linguistic unit which may bring about a change of meaning. For example 'mat' and 'bat'. Phonemes are based on spoken language and recorded by IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet). They are written between slashes e.g. /p/.
>
> - Allophones are variations of phonemes. So, they are set of possible spoken sounds used to pronounce one single phoneme. e.g. [pʰ] (as in *pin*) and [p] (as in *spin*) are allophones of the phoneme /p/. They are written in brackets.
>
> - A phone is a unit of speech sound. It may refer to any speech sound or gesture without regard of its place in phonology of a language. A phoneme is a set of phones or a set of sound features that are thought of as the same element within the phonology of a particular language.

### [Phonemes](https://notendur.hi.is/peturk/KENNSLA/02/TOP/phonemes.html)

> - **Phones** are speech-sounds;
> - **phonemes** are groups of sounds which speakers usually think of as "one sound";
> - **allophones** are the variations within each group.

### [English Language and Literature: Difference between Phones, Allophones and Phonemes.](https://tehreemali176.blogspot.com/2017/01/difference-between-phones-allophones.html)

> **PHONES**
>
> Minimum unit of sound is called phone. OR The speech sounds considered as units of phonetic analysis are called phones.
>
> Phones are any sound of language that can be consistently and individually produced and recognised by the speaker of language. Phones are represented by enclosing the appropriate alphabet/symbol in square bracket. Thus, [p] will refer to p sound (which is described more technically as a voiceless, bilabial sound)
>
> **PHONEME** Each one of these meaning-distinguishing sounds in a language is described as a phoneme. Slash marks are conventionally used to indicate a phoneme, e.g. /t/, an abstract segment, as opposed to the square brackets, as in [t], used for each phonetic or physically produced segment.
>
> **ALLOPHONE**
>   When we have a set of phones, all of which are versions of one phoneme, we add the prefix “allo-” (= one of a closely related set) and refer to them as allophones of that phoneme.

Comment: Which part is particularly befuddling to you?

Comment: @Nardog I just don't feel like I grasped the distinctions. And I'm hankering after "simple real-life analogies".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *phone* is just a sound. That's it. In linguistics, we usually only care about sounds humans are making in order to convey information, but this is still a pretty broad category. Phones are typically written between square brackets, to show that we're talking about a sound and not a letter.

Using a *spectrogram*, it's possible to record a phone, then put it under a microscope and pick it apart to determine its properties. This is called *acoustic phonetics*. Alternately, you can measure exactly what someone is doing with their body in order to create a sound, and determine its properties that way. This is called *articulatory phonetics*. Both are valid.

The problem is…when we're conversing, we hear words as being made up of these nice clean units. We can pick apart "cat" into a "kuh", an "aa", and a "tuh" sound. And once we start taking actual measurements, either dissecting spectrograms or measuring people's tongues moving around, this distinction disappears. If you look on a spectrogram, there's no nice, clear division between the "kuh", and the "aa", and the "tuh". Even worse, there are all sorts of different versions of the English "tuh" sound, which look totally different on a spectrogram, and are made with totally different movements—yet we still hear them all as "tuh"! What's going on here?

Well, what do scientists do when they come across something that doesn't make sense? They make models to explain it! And the most popular model, in this case, says that we have a mental representation, an "underlying form", of the word "cat". This underlying form is made up of three units, a mental "kuh" and a mental "aa" and a mental "tuh", even if the actual sound we produce doesn't have those nice clean divisions. These mental units are called *phonemes*.

*Allophones* are then all the different phones that correspond to a single phoneme. Remember how there are all those different sounds, that look totally different on a spectrogram, but which English-speakers all hear as a "tuh" (which linguists would call `/t/`)? Those are called *allophones* of `/t/`.

And, notably, phonemes and allophones are language-dependent! The sounds `[tʰ]` and `[ʔ]` and `[ɾ]` are all allophones of `/t/` in English, but all belong to different phonemes in Czech. The study of phonemes, these mental models which are specific to a given language, is called *phonology*; the study of phones, the actual sounds that we can measure and examine, is called *phonetics*. As you might imagine, the two have a lot of overlap.